# FactorSquareFree::lrgexp: Exponent is out of bounds for function FactorSquareFree. Error

Tags: plotting, functions, warning-messages, summation

I'm trying to make a two-dimensional contour plot of the temperature of a plate. This is my initial function:

```
T[x_, y_] := 
 (20/Pi) Sum[((-1)^(n + 1)/
    n) Exp[(-n Pi y)/10] Sin[(n Pi x)/10], {n, 1, i}]
```

The function has been acting how I expect it to, so I believe everything is correct with that.

When I tried to plot it, I used:

```
ContourPlot[T[x, y] /. i -> 1, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

I keep getting the error `FactorSquareFree::lrgexp: Exponent is out of bounds for function FactorSquareFree.` This will display three times before the systems suppresses the error and then runs without output until I quit the kernel.

I tried to look at the FactorSquareFree function itself to see if I could figure out where it was going out of bounds. Doing that, I got:

```
FactorSquareFree[T[x, y] /. i -> 1]
-(1/Pi)
 10 I E^(-(1/5) I Pi (x + I y) - 
   1/5 Pi (I x + y)) (E^((2 I Pi x)/5 + 
     1/10 I Pi (x + I y)) - E^(
    1/5 I Pi (x + I y) + 1/10 Pi (I x + y)) + 
    E^(1/5 I Pi (x + I y) + 1/5 Pi (I x + y))
      Log[1 + E^(-(1/10) I Pi (x - I y))] - 
    E^(1/5 I Pi (x + I y) + 1/5 Pi (I x + y))
      Log[E^(-(1/10) I Pi (x - I y)) (1 + E^(
         1/10 I Pi (x - I y)))] - 
    E^((2 I Pi x)/5) Log[1 + E^(1/10 I Pi (x + I y))] + 
    E^(1/5 I Pi (x + I y) + 1/5 Pi (I x + y))
      Log[1 + E^(1/10 I Pi (x + I y))])
```

Looking through that, I don't see anywhere where the exponent should get very large running from {x,0,10} and {y,0,10}.

Everything I have looked up related to this problem has been too complicated for me to understand what solution people were giving. Especially since the issue is with an internal function for ContourPlot, I'm at a loss of what to change or try.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome! It is better to define `T` as this: `T[x_, y_, i_] := (20/Pi) Sum[((-1)^(n + 1)/n) Exp[(-n Pi y)/10] Sin[(n Pi x)/10], {n, 1, i}]`, then you will have analytical expression for `T[x,y,1]` and you can easily plot it. In your approach you need to `Evaluate[T[x,y]/.i->1]` inside plot.

Comment: Definitely use the `Evaluate[]` wrapper as suggested by @Alx. As for those messages, without the initial evaluation the code will reevaluate the symbolic sum for all plot points. These will be machine doubles and any symbolic summation code will convert to rationals. This can give rise to large numerators and denominators, Internal code for symbolic summation will moreover use polynomial algebra functions such as `Factor/FactorSquareFree`. The awkward rationals would then be the cause of those messages.